# Updating structs inside a BTreeSet

Tags: rust

I would like to modify structs inside a `BTreeSet`.

I want to achieve something like the following [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d21776b173fcb6f11e1724f009b2804c):

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd, Debug)]
struct X {
    key: String,
    val: Option<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut set: BTreeSet<X> = BTreeSet::new();
    set.insert(X {
        key: "a".to_string(),
        val: Some(1),
    });
    set.insert(X {
        key: "b".to_string(),
        val: Some(1),
    });
    
    nonify(&mut set, "a".to_string());
    println!("{:?}", set);
}

fn nonify(set: &mut BTreeSet<X>, k: String) {
    for mut s in set.iter() {
        if s.key == k {
            s.val = None;
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work because `s` is not a mutable reference.

How do I accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not safe (in terms of program logic) to modify objects in a `BTreeSet` such that their ordering changes, as doing so would break the internal structure of the set - here's a snippet from the [relevant documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html):

> It is a logic error for an item to be modified in such a way that the item's ordering relative to any other item, as determined by the Ord trait, changes while it is in the set. This is normally only possible through Cell, RefCell, global state, I/O, or unsafe code.

I don't know your exact use case, but since you seem to be using key-value pairs, a [HashMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) or [BTreeMap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) may work here: They don't allow you to mutate the keys for the same reason, but the values associated with the keys may be mutated.

Comment: What if we wanted to modify the value, such that ordering does not change? Maybe ordering is governed by some key attribute, and we want to modify some satellite value..

Comment: Note that the word _safe_ has a very specific meaning in Rust. Changing the order of a keyed value in an ordered container is actually _safe_, but it is a logical error. That is, doing that you will not get a memory corruption or anything unsafe, but you may get an empty container or something.

Comment: @ksceriath for that, you could use a type supporting interior mutability (i.e. `Cell`, `RefCell`, `Mutex`, etc) to allow mutating a specific field when you don't have a mutable reference. You would also want to make sure you manually implement `PartialOrd`/`Ord` for the type, as deriving it will use all fields - even the ones you'd be mutating.

Comment: BTreeSet key-related mutations are needed when working with cryptography. You might use ORE encryption on keys where, e.g. after insertion, you need to remove the left part of the ciphertext to keep tree data safe against inference attack.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to mutate something that Rust does not let you to mutate, you use a `RefCell`. Something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7363ad924b8c5cc16afb944149e3176d):

```
struct X {
    key: String,
    val: RefCell<Option<i32>>,
}
```

Then, to create the value:

```
X {
    key: "some string".to_owned(),
    val: RefCell::new(Some(1)),
}
```

And to mutate it:

```
fn nonify(set: &mut BTreeSet<X>, k: String) {
    for s in set.iter() {
        if s.key == k {
            *s.val.borrow_mut() = None;
        }
    }
}
```

But note that, as [apemanzilla warned in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58790477/2766908), you should not mutate the objects such that their order is changed.